# How can I get more than 20 places using Google Maps For Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, gmaps4rails

Currently I'm using this incredible gem for maps in RoR (thanks Benjamin), and everything is working good. The only problem I have is when I want to get more than 20 places using the function `Gmaps4rails.places_for_address(...)`, I always get the same 20 places as a response. Researching a little bit, I found that the google API works like this, and if you want more than 20 places, you have to paginate through results with the pagetoken https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search. Is there a way to paginate through these results with the `places_for_address`function?, or there is another way to accomplish this task?

Thanks in advance.